# SCD Start and End Date

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, scd

[image]

I am new to ssis and i am a little bit confused about the SCD_Start_Date and SCD_End_Date when we use the SCD dimension wizard. on many examples that i have searched online people always use the "system start time" or "system container " start time. but i am implementing a data warehouse from a scratch but our company have multiple data sources from two or three years ago. so when i upload our data source from these two years into our dw after running the package it will obviously show that, for example, a seller (seller Dimension) changed from department in the day i ran that package but this is wrong because i want to have a reference date that is in the data source (each row has a data_Ref) . isn't this the logic or am i missing something? how do you guys in BI upload old data source with a reference date?

Comment: By definition, the start and end dates of data load are two technical columns to point to the date when data is loaded from an environment to another. Pointing to the date load in the datasource won't help you for the audit of your DWH. You should seperate date loads in the source from the date loads in the DWH.

Comment: What is excatly a reference_date in your case? Is it the following InsertionDate/UpdateDate in the data source?

Comment: ok i understand your explanation makes sense. the data_ref have the date reference each seller makes  everyday. so in our data source from yesterday for example we can have the same BK (same seller) making diferent sales. each sale has a different row. but in a certain column he has a supervisor and this supervisor can change from a certain date (i want historic SCD for the supervisor for ex) , which is supposed to be that data_ref.

Answer (score 1):

SCD Start and End dates are the dates that a version of the record became (or stopped being) the current version in your source system - they have nothing to do with when data was moved between environments (unless that movement was part of a transaction that changed the state of a record).

Going forward, it is relatively easy to create new SCD records and you insert a new version of a record (and update the previous current version of the record) every time there is a change in the source system.

Loading historic data is entirely dependent on your source system. If it only holds the current version of a record then you can only load that single version into your DWH. If the source system, contains a history of the changes made (or, for example, an audit trail of changes made) then you should be able to re-construct the history in a way that allows you to load multiple versions of a record into your DWH